# Oracle String Connection Properties

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle

I've been looking on the website about the String connection and its parameters. I already implemented the connection with this code but I don't know how to concatenate the parameters with user input.

Here's my code :

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OracleClient

Module OracleConnect

   Sub Main()
      Dim connString As String = "server = o92; uid = java2s;password = password;"

      'Create connection
      Dim conn As New OracleConnection(connString)

      Try
         conn.Open()
         Console.WriteLine("Connection Opened")

         Console.WriteLine("Connection Properties")
         Console.WriteLine("- ConnectionString : {0}", conn.ConnectionString)
         Console.WriteLine("- ServerVersion : {0}", conn.ServerVersion)
         Console.WriteLine("- State : {0}", conn.State)

      Catch ex As OracleException
         Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.ToString())
      Finally
         ' Close Connection
         conn.Close()
         Console.WriteLine("Connection Closed")

      End Try

   End Sub
```

The point is I want to change the connection String with user input parameter so it will be a text box and the server and the password and also the listener will be following the user's input.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a function like this, pass in the values of your TextBoxes;

```
Public Function connectionString(server As String, uid As String, password As String) As String
    Dim tmpServer(2) As String

     tmpServer(0) = "server = " & server
    tmpServer(1) = "uid = " & uid
    tmpServer(2) = "password = " & password

    Return String.Join("; ", tmpServer) & ";"
End Function
```

usage would be.

```
Dim conn As New OracleConnection(connectionString(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you started a Console Project rather than a winform Project. The latter will allow you to drag and drop controls like textboxes and buttons on to a form so that users will be able to fill in the Connection String fields.

Then you can concatenate the connection string like this:

```
Dim connString As String = "server = " & Textbox1.Text &"; uid = " & Textbox2.Text &";password = " & Textbox3.Text &";"
```

OR you could use the console application and start it with command line parameters using the [args in the main method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235406%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)